# Why the shape is shifted ion rotation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I would like to draw a similar drawing using tikz
[image]

So far a created a custom shape

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{wesys}[2013/10/16 Wesys Custom Package]

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\tikzset{arc style/.initial={}}

\pgfdeclareshape{windturbine}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}

    \backgroundpath{
        \radius 
        \pgf@xa=\pgf@x 
        \centerpoint \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        \pgfpathcircle{\centerpoint}{\radius/10}


        \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2}{0pt}}}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/20}}
        \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{-\radius/2}{0pt}}}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/20}}

        \begingroup
            \tikz@mode

            \iftikz@mode@fill
                \iftikz@mode@draw
                    \pgfusepath{fill,draw}
                \else
                \pgfusepath{fill}
                    \fi
                \else
                        \iftikz@mode@draw
                    \pgfusepath{draw}
                \fi
            \fi
        \endgroup
    }
}
```

And I started to create a similar drawing as above

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wesys}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter


\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[ windturbine, draw=black,dashed, minimum width=3cm, rotate=-10, xshift=5cm](turbineirot) {};
    \node[ windturbine, draw=black, fill=black, rotate=-40, xshift=5cm, minimum width=3cm,label={[midway,above]i}](turbinei) {};    

    \node[ windturbine, below=2cm of turbinei,rotate=-10, draw=black, fill=black, minimum width=3cm,label={[below= of turbinej, xshift=-8pt]j}](turbinej) {};

    \draw[-] (turbinei.center) -- (turbinej.center)node [midway,right,draw=none] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I am rotating the shapes all are shifted, how can I prevent the shift?
How can I draw the lines with label and angles with label?

Comment: Why do you have a `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` pair in your code without anything between them?

Comment: Your custom shape does some really strange things with the registers.

Comment: I just started to learn, and I used an exmaple as a startup

Answer (score 2):

Your source of problems here is the `xshift` parameter. Your shape is not perfect (as @JohnKormylo mentioned it in a comment), but this issue can be fixed this way (if this is the desired output).

```
\begin{filecontents}{wesys.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{wesys}[2013/10/16 Wesys Custom Package]

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\tikzset{arc style/.initial={}}

\pgfdeclareshape{windturbine}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}

    \backgroundpath{
        \radius 
        \pgf@xa=\pgf@x 
        \centerpoint \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        \pgfpathcircle{\centerpoint}{\radius/10}


        \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2}{0pt}}}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/20}}
        \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{-\radius/2}{0pt}}}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/20}}

        \begingroup
            \tikz@mode

            \iftikz@mode@fill
                \iftikz@mode@draw
                    \pgfusepath{fill,draw}
                \else
                \pgfusepath{fill}
                    \fi
                \else
                        \iftikz@mode@draw
                    \pgfusepath{draw}
                \fi
            \fi
        \endgroup
    }
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wesys}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
            \node[ windturbine, draw=black,dashed, minimum width=3cm, rotate=-10](turbineirot) {};
            \node[ windturbine, draw=black, fill=black, rotate=-40, minimum width=3cm,label={[midway,above]i}](turbinei) {};
        \end{scope};
    \node[ windturbine, below=2cm of turbinei,rotate=-10, draw=black, fill=black, minimum width=3cm,label={[below= of turbinej, xshift=-8pt]j}](turbinej) {};
    \draw[-] (turbinei.center) -- (turbinej.center)node [midway,right,draw=none] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: and you really don't need the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands there.

PS: you may notice the filecontents environment which is used here to create a one-part MWE